# Google Scripts Deploy as web app- how to disaply different gui form on click event

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I built a google gui web app that has basically two gui screens.  The first gui screen has some text entry fields and when the user clicks 'submit' it should pull up the second gui screen displaying some results.

my second gui starts off the same as the first:

```
function displayForm2(hwEntered){
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('800').setWidth('600');;
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
...code and stuff...
app.add(panel);
return app;
}
```

How do I make it work as a web app?

Answer (score 0):

You should build your 2 GUI in the same Ui instance but on 2 separate panels inside a single vertical panel. Then you just have to `setVisible(true)` one panel while you `setVisible(false)` the other one... you can do that either with client handler or server handler, a matter of choice but the client handler is faster and simpler if the button doesn't have other function.
The 'parent panel' (vertical or horizontal) will ensure that each panel will show up at the same place in your display.

You should easily find some explicit examples on this forum